# How can I play mkv files on Droid os 2.2 on a Droid x?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, video, motorola-droid-x

I'd prefer not to have to convert Them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rockplayer looks promising

Comment: Correct. I've tried Rockplayer on my HTC Desire running 2.2 and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

A good, simple and free alternative to RockPlayer I use is VPlayer.

http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/me.abitno.vplayer/